# Fragments added to backstack works perfectly fine, but once it's back on the previous fragment the second fragment does not inflate

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

I have initially added a fragment to my activity. There is a button, whose Onclickmethod replaces the previous fragment with the new one. Once I press the back button it gets back to the previous fragment, so far so good. But when a once again try to click that button, the next fragment doesn't get inflated. Why is that so?

```
    fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.mainFragment,fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

The above piece of code is in OnCreate() and I have added the OnclickListener to the button from the first fragment in onPostResume() method, as shown in the following piece of code from the OnClickListner method.

```
    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    TakeDataFragment fragment=new TakeDataFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainFragment,fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

It works perfectly fine once, but after getting back from the second fragment on the first one, it does not inflate the second fragment even on button click event.

Comment: Note: Both the FragmentManager and the FragmentTransaction belong to the  android.app package.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved, I was using the callback methods of an activity to set the onClickListners to the buttons that were inside the first fragment. Now I have used the onResume() call back method of the fragment and works fine. Thanks!